# set state based off option value in a select

Tags: reactjs

How can I use the options in the select in my state?

```
 this.state = {
        posts: [],
        question: '',
        body: '',
        postType: '', 
      }

             <select value="types" className="u-full-width">
                <option value="Option 1">Question</option>
                <option value="Option 2">Discussion</option>
                <option value="Option 3">Clout</option>
              </select>
```

I am not sure how to set the state of postType based off what the user selects.

```
       getPostType() {
        const type = 
        this.setState({ postType: type });
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a function to handle the changes on the select, save the value in the state and pass it to the select.

Something like this:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
     this.state = {
        postType: 'Option 1', 
      }
 this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
};


onChange(event){
 this.setState({
   postType: event.target.value
 })
}


render() {
    return (
       <div>
          <select value={this.state.postType} onChange={this.onChange} className="u-full-width">
                <option value="Option 1">Question</option>
                <option value="Option 2">Discussion</option>
                <option value="Option 3">Clout</option>
              </select>  
             {this.state.postType}
       </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
   <App />,
   document.getElementById('container')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

This is called a controlled component. You can read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components).

Comment: see the problem with this is if its on question it does not default to question, you literally have to reselect question.

Comment: @Omar I understand. Remember to bind `this` to your `getPostType` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following implementation.

```
class Sample extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    posts: [],
    question: '',
    body: '',
    postType: 'Question', 
  }
  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}

handleChange(event) {
  this.setState({postType: event.target.value});
}

render() {
  return (
    <form>
    <label>
      Select your postType:
      <select className="u-full-width" value={this.state.postType} 
       onChange={this.handleChange}>
            <option value="Question">Question</option>
            <option value="Discussion">Discussion</option>
            <option value="Clout">Clout</option>
      </select> 
    </label>
    </form>
   );
  }
}

 ReactDOM.render(
  <Sample />,
  document.getElementById('root')
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you're looking for is the following:

```
<select className="u-full-width" 
        onChange= this.handleOnChange.bind(this)
        ref={value => this.refName = value}>
    <option value="Option 1">Question</option>
    <option value="Option 2">Discussion</option>
    <option value="Option 3">Clout</option>
</select>

handleOnchange(e){
    e.preventDefault(e);
    const type = this.refName.value;
    setState({postType: type});
}
```

Hope it was helpful!